# Evaluating an inequality symbolically

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to verify an inequality using the symbolic solver in Matlab. Matlab is able to tell me that the first inequality below is true, however, the second one fails. Am I doing something wrong here, or is the second expression to complex for Matlab?

```
syms mu sigma rho lambdaP

assume(mu>0)
assume(sigma>0)
assume(rho>0)
assume(lambdaP>0)
assume(rho>mu)

b=(mu-0.5*sigma^2);
isAlways(sqrt(b^2+2*sigma^2)>=0)
isAlways(sqrt(b^2+2*sigma^2*(rho+lambdaP))>=0)
```

Comment: It may be indeed too complex for Matlab. What happens if you explicitly add `assume(rho>0)`
.

Comment: Can your variables be complex numbers? If not, you could add `assumeAlso(symvar, 'real')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second assumption on the variables `rho` and `mu`, you should use `assumeAlso` instead of `assume`. Calling `assume` again on a symbolic variable removes the first assumption. You can also remove all the separate `assume` lines, by adding the assumption to the declaration of the symbolic variables

```
syms mu sigma rho lambdaP positive

assumeAlso(rho>mu)

b=(mu-0.5*sigma^2);
isAlways(sqrt(b^2+2*sigma^2)>=0)
isAlways(sqrt(b^2+2*sigma^2*(rho+lambdaP))>=0)
```

This will return true for both expressions.

You can check the assumptions per variable by typing e.g. `assumptions(rho)`. If you do not use `assumeAlso`, you will see that the `> 0` assumption is gone.